# relational database design for multidimensional matrix questions

Tags: database, schema, relational

I am designing a relational DB for an online survey.

However, I am not sure what is the best relational database design for storing multidimensional matrix questions.

Let's say, I have the following question (sorry, it does not allow me to insert HTML table):

What was your experience of...

```
----------| Not friendly| (2) |Very friendly|Length of stay|Visited in the last year?|
Sydney    |radio button |  rb |        rb   |   drop down  |  check box              |   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New York  |     rb      |  rb |        rb   |   drop down  |  check box              | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
London    |     rb      |  rb |        rb   |   drop down  |  check box              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do you think I should do something along the following lines or is there a better way?

To hold all the question:

**Question**
questionID
question

**QuestionMatrix2d**
matrix2dID
questionID
subquestionID
subquestion

**QuestionMatrix**
questionID
matrix2dID
question_parentID

And to hold all the responses:

**QuestionResponse**
questionID
response_code

**QuestionMatrix2dResponse**
questionID
subquestionID
response_code

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with ryan1234. This totally is a relational problem, and there is very little reason not to put it into a database.

I have to do a bit of guesswork though, in what you're trying to achieve here. You have an online survey, so I assume it will be used by more than one person. Your database will need to acommodate for that by having a `session` or `user` table, I'll go with the latter since it is more clear to read.

Secondly, you have a list of `locations` (Sidney, New York, London). I assume this list can either change over time or even from one questionaire to the next.

Then you have a set of `questions`. You don't explicitly state that these would be variable or fixed. Since you designed a set of tables for that, I assume it's supposed to be variable. Please note that your questions are not a matrix, but a list. Even if they are hierarchical, they still do not compose a matrix.

Last but not least you've got answers to those questions.

Lets create a `users` table:

```
user_id  user_name  
1        me
2        somebody else
```

Second table is as simple: `locations`

```
location_id    location_name
1              Sidney
2              New York
3              London
```

Third table is a bit more complicated - and to be honest: just plain ugly. But this is what you get if you design a database in a database, and the alternatives (using DDL or storing that information in XML/JSON or even outside the database) are not pretty either. If there is a hierarchical question (your examples don't show them), you could add a "parent_question_id" column.

```
question_id    question_text      question_type    question_type_info
1              How do you rate    RADIO            0 to 5
2              Length of stay     COMBOBOX         1 day, 2 days, whatever
3              Visited last year  CHECKBOX
```

Finally you need a fourth table to store all the answers

```
user_id    location_id     question_id     value
1          1               1               2          <-- value here means "rating of 2"
1          1               2               5          <-- value here means "5 days"
1          1               3               1          <-- value here means "yes, visited last year"
```

Yep. ugly as well. If you had a fixed list of questions I could provide you with a pretty database :)

**Edit:** Answering to your comments: To link your questions to a survey, you'll need a few more tables `surveys` defining which questions for which locations are going to be asked. The following database layout lets you specify a list of locations and a list of questions asked as well as a survey name.

Table `surveys`:

```
survey_id survey_name
1         Spring 2013 London Travel Survey
2         Spring 2013 Northern Hemisphere Short Survey
```

Table `survey_questions`:

```
survey_id question_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
```

Table `survey_locations`:

```
survey_id location_id
1         1
2         1
2         2
```

The contents I put in here gives you two surveys. Survey #1 will ask all three questions just on one location: 'London'. Survey #2 will just ask one question on both London and New York. If you want to ask different questions on different locations your table layout will have to accommodate for that, but such a system won't fit into your original table-like layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right - it is going to be used by multiple users and questions can change from survey to survey. However, what do you think is the best way to show that all these questions are related to What was your experience of...? as it is important for people who are going to analyse the data to know how the questions were asked exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The fourth table `answers` has a column `question_id` which directly links to the `questions` table which in turn has the question.

Comment: There are going to be external people looking at these surveys. For some of the questions, it is important to know exactly how the question was asked, so the introductory question 'What was your experience of...' has not got any responses but when people look at the survey, they need to know that it was asked as an introduction. I suppose it is important to know how the questions relate to each other when the survey is generated to be displayed to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Having done things similar to this, I would recommend considering *not* turning this into a relational problem. What if you have objects and just serialize them to something like JSON and store that?

Doing this relationally you'll end up spending quite a bit of time making tables and wiring together complex drawing code in your application to make sure the questions/answers draw in the right order etc.

Otherwise I think you can make your approach work. There is no silver bullet for designing survey stuff in an RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you - the data has to be available for querying. If I store it as JSON, I am not sure I will be able to do it very easily. I know there was some development for JSON queries but is there some standard?